# Chrome style slide range issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, slider, range

I was doing some coding and suddently i reload and some of my element's width isn't the same and all of the sliders of any website style is this way:

[image]

does anybody knows what's happening, has chrome made an update?

EDIT:

I downloaded an older version of chrome and now everything works like it used to do:
[image]

anyone knows if this is due to an update?

EDIT: I have had that issue again and here is the css linked with the range sliders:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: there is no code its on any website

Comment: This is not a standard progress, I think it's a custom one, and it needs css to be applied here

Comment: it showed that even without any script

Comment: Just to say, I'm facing the same problem, so look like Chrome updated the way to display range with adding a blue trail.

Comment: @Mimiste if you need to go back just download the previous version of chrome here: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php